# Need to create a dependency mapping table using python or pyspark or sql

Tags: python, sql, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

If we have two column source and target, from this input table i need to create a dependency table at lowest granularity means A's target table is B similarly B point to C and C point to D.

Output table will show that L3 is highest level and L0 is lowest level.
Similar way I have 1000+ records in source,target table from which i need to make mapping output table like below

Note:
A can have multiple targets similarly B,C can also have so we have to make a arrange in a way that each source and target will have proper level

| Source | Target |
| --- | --- |
| A | B |
| B | C |
| C | D |

o/p

| L3 | L2 | L1 | L0 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | B | C | D |

Comment: You don't really want to store this in an SQL table, do you?  What if there are more than 4 levels?  What you have here is a directed graph.  There is a `networkx` module for Python that lets you build and manage a directed graph, and do whatever analysis you need to do.

Comment: Hi Tim, Thank you for your time, actually i am not familiar with this module to make graphs so if you can suggest any other alternative or make a code using networkx module for this 4 level that would be helpful for me

Comment: We can't do your coding for you, because we don't know what you intend to DO with this graph.  What you have in your original table is the usual way to store a directed graph, because it's completely general.  No duplicates, and no limitations.